# AutoLayout constraints to fit view inside rectangle, preserving a certain aspect ratio (programmatically)

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout, snapkit

I want to fit an image inside a rectangle that should have a specific aspect ratio. No matter what it is, it should find a form to fit inside the rectangle. I played around in storyboard and got this:

[image]

The ones with the dotted border have low priority (250).
This works in the storyboard. However, I need to create these constraints programmatically, so I tried it like this (I'm using [SnapKit](https://github.com/SnapKit/SnapKit), which simply provides better `AutoLayout` syntax. It should be self-explaining):

```
let topView = UIView()
topView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
topView.backgroundColor = .gray
view.addSubview(topView)

topView.snp.makeConstraints { (make) in
        make.top.equalToSuperview()
        make.left.equalToSuperview()
        make.trailing.equalToSuperview()
        make.height.equalTo(250)
        }

// This view should have a specific aspect ratio and fit inside topView
let holderView = UIView()
holderView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
holderView.backgroundColor = .red
topView.addSubview(holderView)

holderView.snp.makeConstraints { (make) in
        make.center.equalToSuperview() // If I remove this one, there's no auto-layout issue, but then it's offset
        make.edges.equalToSuperview().priority(250) // sets leading, trailing, top and bottom
        make.edges.greaterThanOrEqualToSuperview().priority(1000)
        make.width.equalTo(holderView.snp.height).multipliedBy(3/2)
        }
```

If you paste this into an empty ViewController and start it up, you get these issues:

```
2018-03-16 15:38:50.188867+0100 DemoProject[11298:850932] [LayoutConstraints] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. 
Try this: 
    (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; 
    (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. 

"<SnapKit.LayoutConstraint:0x6000000a7c80@ViewController.swift#24 UIView:0x7fcd82d12440.left == UIView:0x7fcd82d12640.left>",
"<SnapKit.LayoutConstraint:0x6000000a7ce0@ViewController.swift#25 UIView:0x7fcd82d12440.trailing == UIView:0x7fcd82d12640.trailing>",
"<SnapKit.LayoutConstraint:0x6000000a7d40@ViewController.swift#26 UIView:0x7fcd82d12440.height == 250.0>",
"<SnapKit.LayoutConstraint:0x6000000a7da0@ViewController.swift#35 UIView:0x7fcd8580dad0.centerX == UIView:0x7fcd82d12440.centerX>",
"<SnapKit.LayoutConstraint:0x6000000a7e00@ViewController.swift#35 UIView:0x7fcd8580dad0.centerY == UIView:0x7fcd82d12440.centerY>",
"<SnapKit.LayoutConstraint:0x6000000a8580@ViewController.swift#37 UIView:0x7fcd8580dad0.top >= UIView:0x7fcd82d12440.top>",
"<SnapKit.LayoutConstraint:0x6000000a8a60@ViewController.swift#37 UIView:0x7fcd8580dad0.right >= UIView:0x7fcd82d12440.right>",
"<SnapKit.LayoutConstraint:0x6000000a9360@ViewController.swift#38 UIView:0x7fcd8580dad0.width == UIView:0x7fcd8580dad0.height>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x600000092cf0 'UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Width' UIView:0x7fcd82d12640.width == 414   (active)>"


Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint <SnapKit.LayoutConstraint:0x6000000a9360@ViewController.swift#38 UIView:0x7fcd8580dad0.width == UIView:0x7fcd8580dad0.height>
```

This doesn't show up, when I remove the centering constraint `make.center.equalToSuperview()`. But then, it's misplaced.

What is different between the storyboard and my code? I don't really understand this. I also tried this using the default swift syntax, the result was exactly the same. So I don't think it's a problem with `SnapKit`

Any ideas? Thank you guys for any help. Let me know if you need any more infos.

EDIT: I mixed something up. It's not about the image and its aspect ratio. It's just about a `UIView` that should maintain a specific aspect ratio while fitting inside a rectangle. The actual image will just be put into that `holderView`. Sorry

Comment: Anyreason why the imageView is not simply linked to the holder edges and using `.scaleAspectFit` ?

Comment: hard to explain, but I'll try: I've got a `collection view` that is full of differently sized cells. Each cell is covered by a `UIImageView` (linked to the cell's edges) set to `.scaleAspectFill`. Now I need a smaller representation of what the cell with the image looks like in another `view controller`, where you can move it around to place/rotate/scale the image (aspectFill 'zooms' the image to fit, and you should be able to kind of say how it's placed in the cell)

Comment: I realize it's not so much about an `ImageView`, really. I'm gonna edit the title. The image will indeed just be linked to the `holderView`s edges. Its the holder view that has to have the aspect ratio of the cell. Sorry, I mixed that up

Comment: You have way too many constraints. You can either constrain two edges and the width/height **or** the center and width/height **or**  four edges (and if you are using an aspect ratio constraint, set only width **or** height)

Comment: It looks like you're trying to set the `width` of the imageView equal to the `height` of the imageView * 3/2... but you are *also* setting the edges of the imageView to its superview. You probably want to set one or the other, not both.

Comment: You can also use http://wtfautolayout.com for help

Comment: It's working, though. At least in the storyboard it's not giving me any errors or warnings. I don't see why it shouldn't work, to be honest. If the aspect ratio is 1:1, for instance, and the square is not as wide as the screen (`topView`) the square will have the same height as `topView`. Width would be the same (1:1). If would be placed in the center of `topView`. Not a single constraint would be violated (width/height is okay, its centered, and its >=0 from the edges, which is required)

Comment: @DonMag yes, but I'm giving them the requirement to be "greater than or equal to 0" from the edges. The "=0" from edges constraints have low priority so Auto-Layout won't force it

Comment: @Quantm - you are setting `topView` to the full width of its superview, with a height of `250` ... do you want your imageView to stretch the full *width*, and allow the aspect ratio to control its *height*? Or do you want the imageView to stretch the full *height* and allow the aspect ratio to control its *width*?

Comment: That's the critical point (that's where I was before as well): It depends on the aspect ratio. I tried to visualize it: https://imgur.com/a/SF1LJ. It has to try and fit so that everything is visible, on-screen (that's what the ">=0" constraints are there for. To guarantee that)

Comment: (Maybe I haven't explained it that well in the question. I'm sorry if that's the case. It's hard to explain these kinds of things in a written text)

Comment: hmm... so, you want to "scale aspect fit" the `holderVIew` subview inside the `topView` superview? Centered either vertically or horizontally as appropriate?

Comment: Yes, that's basically it (that's more on-point than what I wrote :D). But it should be centered vertically *and* horizontally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK - here is **one** way to do it.

Take the "native" size of your subview, calculate the "aspect fit" ratio - that is, the ratio that will fit the width or height to the superview, and scale the other dimension appropriately.

Then, use `centerXAnchor` and `centerYAnchor` to position the subview, and `widthAnchor` and `heightAnchor` to size it.

Note: if you're trying to place an **image**, calculate the aspect fit size from the image size, put the image in an image view, set the image view scale mode to `fill`, and finally apply the constraints to the image view.

You should be able to run this example as-is. Just play around with the "native" size values at the top to see how it fits the subview into the superview.

```
public class AspectFitViewController : UIViewController {

    // "native" size for the holderView
    let hViewWidth: CGFloat = 700.0
    let hViewHeight: CGFloat = 200.0

    let topView: UIView = {
        let v = UIView()
        v.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        v.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue
        return v
    }()

    let holderView: UIView = {
        let v = UIView()
        v.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        v.backgroundColor = UIColor.cyan
        return v
    }()

    public override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        view.bounds = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 400, height: 600)
        view.backgroundColor = .yellow

        // add topView
        view.addSubview(topView)

        // pin topView to leading / top / trailing
        topView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor, constant: 0.0).isActive = true
        topView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor, constant: 0.0).isActive = true
        topView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor, constant: 0.0).isActive = true

        // explicit height for topView
        topView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 250.0).isActive = true

        // add holderView to topView
        topView.addSubview(holderView)

        // center X and Y
        holderView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topView.centerXAnchor, constant: 0.0).isActive = true
        holderView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topView.centerYAnchor, constant: 0.0).isActive = true

        // holderView's width and height will be calculated in viewDidAppear
        // after topView has been laid-out by the auto-layout engine

    }

    public override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)

        let aspectWidth  = topView.bounds.size.width / hViewWidth
        let aspectHeight = topView.bounds.size.height / hViewHeight

        let aspectFit = min(aspectWidth, aspectHeight)

        let newWidth = hViewWidth * aspectFit
        let newHeight = hViewHeight * aspectFit

        holderView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: newWidth).isActive = true
        holderView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: newHeight).isActive = true

    }

}
```

---

**Edit:**

After clarification... this *can* be accomplished by constraints only. The key is that "Priority 1000" `top` and `leading` constraints must be `.greaterThanOrEqual` to zero, and the `bottom` and `trailing` constraints must be `.lessThanOrEqual` to zero.

```
public class AspectFitViewController : UIViewController {

    // "native" size for the holderView
    let hViewWidth: CGFloat = 700.0
    let hViewHeight: CGFloat = 200.0

    let topView: UIView = {
        let v = UIView()
        v.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        v.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue
        return v
    }()

    let holderView: UIView = {
        let v = UIView()
        v.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        v.backgroundColor = UIColor.cyan
        return v
    }()

    public override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        view.bounds = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 400, height: 600)
        view.backgroundColor = .yellow

        // add topView
        view.addSubview(topView)

        // pin topView to leading / top / trailing
        topView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor, constant: 0.0).isActive = true
        topView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor, constant: 0.0).isActive = true
        topView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor, constant: 0.0).isActive = true

        // explicit height for topView
        topView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 250.0).isActive = true

        // add holderView to topView
        topView.addSubview(holderView)

        // center X and Y
        holderView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topView.centerXAnchor, constant: 0.0).isActive = true
        holderView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topView.centerYAnchor, constant: 0.0).isActive = true

        // aspect ratio size
        holderView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: holderView.heightAnchor, multiplier: hViewWidth / hViewHeight).isActive = true

        // two constraints for each side...
        // the .equal constraints need .defaultLow priority
        // top and leading constraints must be .greaterThanOrEqual to 0
        // bottom and trailing constraints must be .lessThanOrEqual to 0

        let topA = NSLayoutConstraint(item: holderView, attribute: .top, relatedBy: .greaterThanOrEqual, toItem: topView, attribute: .top, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0.0)
        let topB = NSLayoutConstraint(item: holderView, attribute: .top, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: topView, attribute: .top, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0.0)

        let bottomA = NSLayoutConstraint(item: holderView, attribute: .bottom, relatedBy: .lessThanOrEqual, toItem: topView, attribute: .bottom, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0.0)
        let bottomB = NSLayoutConstraint(item: holderView, attribute: .bottom, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: topView, attribute: .bottom, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0.0)

        let leadingA = NSLayoutConstraint(item: holderView, attribute: .leading, relatedBy: .greaterThanOrEqual, toItem: topView, attribute: .leading, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0.0)
        let leadingB = NSLayoutConstraint(item: holderView, attribute: .leading, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: topView, attribute: .leading, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0.0)

        let trailingA = NSLayoutConstraint(item: holderView, attribute: .trailing, relatedBy: .lessThanOrEqual, toItem: topView, attribute: .trailing, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0.0)
        let trailingB = NSLayoutConstraint(item: holderView, attribute: .trailing, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: topView, attribute: .trailing, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0.0)

        topB.priority = .defaultLow
        bottomB.priority = .defaultLow
        leadingB.priority = .defaultLow
        trailingB.priority = .defaultLow

        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            topA, topB,
            bottomA, bottomB,
            leadingA, leadingB,
            trailingA, trailingB
            ])

    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I had a similar version of this before (though it didn't quite work. Your version works perfectly), but I find this slightly inconvenient when it *should* work without manually calculating anything. (It's working using storyboard, so it *has to work* using code only as well. That's what I don't understand). But I guess I'd have to stick with calculation width/heigh manually if nobody has an idea why the code isn't working. Thanks anyways.

Comment: @Quantm - Ah --- now I understand. See my edited answer, specifically the comments.

Comment: wow, this does work (though I think it should be `hViewHeight / hViewWidth`, not `hViewWidth / hViewHeight`). But why should it be lessThanOrEqualTo? I don't quite get that. Shouldn't this mean that parts can be off-screen?
But a huge thank you for this effort. I really appreciate it!

Comment: Whoops - I transposed the width-to-height ratio... fixed now. When you set the trailing and bottom constraints in storyboard, IB automatically sets First Item: Superview, Second Item: Subview... so it is `>= 0`. Setting it from code is *generally* easier to think in terms of "subview-to-superview" so you need to make it `<= 0`. Very common when coding to "I want it 20-pts from the bottom" and getting it wrong when setting it to `+20` instead of `-20`.

Comment: ooooohhhh, dang it. Right, I never thought about that. Makes sense. Thank you! :)